# Flutter - Why formKey.currentState.reset doesn't actually clear fields?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart

What I want to do is clear the entries after canceling the form submission. I'm trying to use *_formKey.currentState.reset()* but the fields are not being cleaned up. Should I have a method for cleaning field by field? Below I will show my code with the user name and weight fields but I have other fields (DropdownButton and Radio) that I decided not to put in the code so as not to get too long:

```
class UserDetailForm extends StatefulWidget {
  final User user;
  const UserDetailForm(this.user);

  @override
  _UserDetailFormState createState() => _UserDetailFormState();
}

class _UserDetailFormState extends State<UserDetailForm> {
  final UserController controller = UserController();
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0, horizontal: 16.0),
        child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          autovalidate: true,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              TextFormField(
                  initialValue: widget.user.name,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Name *'),
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value.isEmpty) {
                      return 'Insert your name';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() => widget.user.name = value);
                  }),
             
              TextFormField(
                  initialValue: widget.user.weight,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Weight',
                  ),
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() => widget.user.weight = value);
                  }),

              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: <Widget>[
                  MaterialButton(
                    child: Text("Cancel"),
                      onPressed: () {
                        _formKey.currentState.reset(); //NOT WORKING, SHOULD CLEAN THE FORM 
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      },
                      ),
                  MaterialButton(
                    child: Text("Save"),
                      onPressed: () async {
                        if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                          controller.updateUser(widget.user);
                          Navigator.of(context).pop();
                        }
                      },
                      ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**#Edit 1 - Using TextEditingController (only for weight) and the problem still,  the entries after canceling the form submission are not being cleaned up**

```
class UserDetailForm extends StatefulWidget {
  final User user;
  const UserDetailForm(this.user);

  @override
  _UserDetailFormState createState() => _UserDetailFormState();
}

class _UserDetailFormState extends State<UserDetailForm> {
  final UserController controller = UserController();
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  TextEditingController weightController;

  initState() {
    weightController = TextEditingController(text: widget.user.weight);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0, horizontal: 16.0),
        child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          autovalidate: true,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              TextFormField(
                  initialValue: widget.user.name,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Name *'),
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value.isEmpty) {
                      return 'Insert your name';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() => widget.user.name = value);
                  }),

              TextFormField(
                controller: weightController,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Weight',
                  ),
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() => widget.user.weight = value);
                  }),

              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: <Widget>[
                  MaterialButton(
                    child: Text("Cancel"),
                    onPressed: () {
                      _formKey.currentState.reset();
                      weightController.text = "";
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    },
                  ),
                  MaterialButton(
                    child: Text("Save"),
                    onPressed: () async {
                      if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                        controller.updateUser(widget.user);
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`_formKey.currentState.reset()` resets every FormField that is a descendant of this Form back to its `FormField.initialValue`, and that's what is happening in your code. When clicking cancel, the initialValue is still in the screen. To fix that, you need to use a `TextEditingController`. So first initialize the controller:

```
  TextEditingController weightController = TextEditingController(text: "test");
  TextEditingController nameController   = TextEditingController(text: "test1");
```

And give each controller an initial value (ex: test). Then bind each `controller` the `field`:

```
         TextFormField(
                controller : emailController,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Name *'),
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value.isEmpty) {
                      return 'Insert your name';
                    }
                    return null;
                  }),
             
              TextFormField(
                controller: nameController,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Weight',
                  )),
```

remove the `initialValue` property since you are already initializing the field when creating a controller. Finally under `onPressed()`:

```
                      onPressed: () {
                        _formKey.currentState.reset();
                        nameController.text = "";
                        emailController.text = "";
                       
                      },
```

change the value of the initial test to empty `string`.

Comment: thanks for the reply but still the form does not clean. I think is something with widget.user.weight / widget.user.name that holds the input but I haven't figured out how fix

Comment: did you initialize it inside the controller? `TextEditingController weightController = TextEditingController(text: widget.user.weight);`

Comment: yes, i did. i also added the new code on #Edit 1, can you check? cleaning the controller inside onPressed doesn't work but if i put widget.user.weight getting an empty string, it works. although functional, I don't know if cleaning field by field is the correct way

Comment: If it is not clearing then why did you accept the answer? @LiamPark

Comment: Any other solution to clear the field?